# How to reference query values inside another Prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to create a rule that will take as filter output from a recorded rule.

I've created an alerting rule that should monitor whether a recent cronjob has failed.
I use a recoding rule to get a timestemp of the last run of the cronjob and want to use that value to filter out the job with failed status set too true. I've tried few things but seams like I'm not able to reference the recorded value within the next query.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  name: cron-job-alerts
  namespace: openshift-monitoring
  labels:
    openshift.io/prometheus-rule-evaluation-scope: leaf-prometheus
spec:
  groups:
  - name: kube-cron
    rules:
    - record: job_cronjob:job:name
      expr: |
        kube_cronjob_labels{namespace="dev-v1", label_cronjob="weekly-availability-reporting-cronjob"} * on() kube_cronjob_status_last_schedule_time{namespace="dev-v1"}
    - alert: CronJobStatusFailed
      expr: |
        kube_job_failed{namespace="dev-v1",condition="true", job_name="weekly-availability-reporting-cronjob-{{ job_cronjob:job:name}}"}==1
#      for: 1m
      annotations:
        description: 'Attempt 1'
```

Does somebody know how to properly reference the job_cronjob:job:name value within the expression filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, alerting rules allow [templating](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/#templating) only in label and annotation values but not in the alert expression.

Generally, I wouldn't pin down the Job that you want to alert on by its name, but simply do:

```yaml
- alert: CronJobStatusFailed
  expr: kube_job_failed{namespace="dev-v1", condition="true"} == 1
  annotations:
    description: Job {{ $labels.job_name }} failed.
```

In this way, you get an alert whenever a Job fails, including every execution of a CronJob.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's unfortunate one cannot use templating within the expression. I wanted to ensure that I only going to check the status of the last job that ran. I belive the expression you shared works too but it will require to limit the history of failed jobs just to one. I think.

Comment: Yes, there will be an alert for every failed Job, not only the last one. I don't know if there's an easy way to select just the last failed Job of a CronJob.

Comment: I've quickly tested it and limiting the history helps, but the alert is still firing when the next job succeeds. I will need to somehow ensure the alert is resolved if follow up job complets successfully.

Comment: You could route the alert to a custom [webhook receiver](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#webhook_config) in the Alertmanager which deletes the failed Job after a certain amount of time, e.g. equal to the CronJob interval. This way, each alert is automatically resolved when the next Job starts.